# Flex : converting seconds to readable english

Tags: apache-flex, datetime, actionscript

For example :
input = 360 seconds
output  = 6 minutes

input = 86400
output = 1 day

Is there a built-in method for this.
I did find something similar [here](http://polygeek.com/513_actionscript3_converting-seconds-to-english-readable-time-duration).

Just want to know if there is a built-in method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

not per se, but the use of the [`Date`](https://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html) class makes this pretty straight-forward.